# Launch Java application in new process

Tags: java, process, exec, processbuilder

I have a Java application which I launch e.g. with "ant myapp". Now I want that this application replicates itself, i.e. starts new instances of it in new processes.

I know that it should be done with the Processbuilder or with Runtime.exec().

If I'm just calling in the Processbuilder or Runtime.exec('ant myapp') it will start a new JVM and runs it in a separate process. Is this right?

But I have also heard that it is possible to run the application in a new process but within the same JVM. How can I do this?

If I don't have a new JVM then less memory is consumed. But what are the disadvantages if the new process is running in the same JVM? I have lot of sockets connections to a server in the application. So perhaps this is a problem when not creating a new JVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `ExecutorService`.  You can pool them, set timeouts, etc.

As for sockets, memory, CPU: you should profile your app to make sure that you're using finite resources appropriately.  This is true for all Java applications.  You can't know the answer by guessing or asking here.  Every situation is different.  The only way to know is to get some data by profiling.

Comment: ExecutorService is for creating new processes within the same JVM? And they will be run as new processes? How can I do profiling?

Comment: Think of it as a better, safer Thread.   No, they won't show up as a PID on the OS.  They run inside the single JVM.  You profile with a profiling tool, like VisualVM or dynaTrace (my new fave).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an easy step-by-step tutorial for setting up VisualVM or dynaTrace on a Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu and conncect to it from my Windows host?

Comment: No, you're on your own there.  dynaTrace is expensive; not likely to be available on EC2.  Visual VM is bundled with the JVM; see if you can run it in the command shell.